# Windows 11 add custom buton on new context menu (right click menu)

Tags: windows, contextmenu, right-click, regedit

On Windows 10, I had created a button in the menu that called a python script ([see project](https://github.com/EnzoDeg40/EdShare)). I had managed to do this by modifying values in the registry editor.

[image: Old rightclik]

My button still appears on Windows 11 but only on the old menu and not the new one. You must now click on “More option” to display all the options.
I know it's possible to disable it on the new menu but I don't want to, I really want to add a button on the new. I think it is possible by modifying data in the register editor.

[image: New rightclick menu]

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Despite not providing a full repro in question, I think that's a good question to ask here. Tried to find this myself - but didnt really get much (tried comparing registry snapshots).

Comment: Can only add that that's not quite as easy as it was on older context menu. To get to the same point where I am - try getting a snapshot (you can find software for that online), get a snapshot, install WinRar which has it, take another, and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool that allows you to add elements on new context menu

https://github.com/ikas-mc/ContextMenuForWindows11

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft changed Windows 11 on purpose to prevent people from easily adding entries to the context menu.

The only way to display your item in the new context menu is to implement a [`IExplorerCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommand) COM object and on top of that, your application needs to be packaged (app identity with a sparse manifest) and signed with a valid certificate.

This was announced on the Windows blog last year [in this post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/).